# Unpacking the arguments before feeding it to a `map` function

Tags: python

```py
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[0] * x[1], d.items()))
['a', 'bb']
```

I'd rather be able to name my variables in my function, but
this

```py
>>> list(map(lambda k, v: k * v, d.items()))
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v'
```

obviously won't work since `map` feeds single inputs to the function.

What I've done for myself is write a decorator (here simplified);

```py
def asterisk(func):
    def _func(single_input):
        return func(*single_input)
    return _func
```

that then allows me to do this

```py
>>> list(map(asterisk(lambda k, v: k * v), d.items()))
['a', 'bb']
```

But I can't help but think I'm missing a simple trick or builtin function here.

Comment: `list(itertools.starmap(operator.mul, d.items()))`

Comment: Why not just `list(k * v for k, v in d.items())`?

Comment: @Rfroes87 Presumably because this is a trivial example, and using `map` with a given callback function is still useful…

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `generator expression` for `list` like so:

```
list(k * v for k, v in d.items())
```